# Are there any iOS games that involve game theory?

Tags: ios, software-recommendation, games

The closest I found is Topia World Builder, but it's unclear to me if the predator/prey dynamic is based on game theory or is some generic algorithm. Seems this would be a simple game to implement, so I'm surprised there are many varieties, or anything really, in the App Store.

Comment: You have an interesting concept there. Game theory is applicable to most of life's conundrums, but to make it into a game? That's fascinating.

Comment: Let me know if you're interested to develop something... ;)

Comment: I'll have to brush up on my Game theory, but I may be interested.